# How to clone business units in marketing cloud?

Tags: marketing-cloud, deployment, data-migration

I have multiple business units in the marketing cloud. Is there any way to clone one business unit data like(journey, data extensions, contact, and contents) to the new business unit?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't clone an entire business unit, but the recently introduced [Package Manager](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=sf.mc_overview_marketing_cloud_package_manager.htm&type=5) can take you quite far.

Package Manager is under constant development, and the list of supported assets is expected to increase in the future. At the moment, it can help you create snapshots and deploy following objects across multiple business units:

[image]